# Picking up (next_siblings) texts

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

(Environment: Python 2.7 + BeautifulSoup 4.3.2)

Purpose: pick up the text “Jan 23, 2009 12:05 pm” in the code.

Because the webpage is in the company website requires login and redirection, so I copy the source codes of the target page into a file and save it as “example.html” in C:\ for the convenience of practising.

This is part of the original code:

```
<tr class="ghj">
  <td>
    <span class="city-sh">
      <sh src="./citys/1.jpg" alt="boy" title="boy" />
    </span>
    <a href="./membercity.php?mode=view&amp;u=12563">port_new_cape</a>
  </td>
  <td class="position">
      <a href="./search.php?id=12563&amp;sr=positions"
        title="Search positions">452</a>
  </td>
  <td class="details">
      <div>South</div>
  </td>
  <td>May 09, 1997</td>
  <td>Jan 23, 2009 12:05 pm&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

The codes so far I worked out is:

```
url = r"C:\example.html"
page = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

cities = soup.find_all('td', {'class' : details}) 
sis = cities.find_next_siblings('td')

for s in sis:
    print s
```

I don’t know how to pick it up directly so routing the siblings. However when I run it, it gives error message like below, seems it cannot recognize the siblings.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/Last Activity mydyingbride.py", line 17, in <module>
sis = cities.find_next_siblings('td')
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_next_siblings'
```

In what way, can I practice by using a local file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Python debugger to see the current-value of variables. Anyways, here is the solution:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
cities = soup.find_all('td', {'class' : 'details'}) 
counter = 0
while len(cities) > counter:
    sis = cities[counter].find_next_siblings('td')

    for s in sis:
        print s

    counter += 1
```

Output is:

```
<td>May 09, 1997</td>
<td>Jan 23, 2009 12:05 pm┬á</td>
```

To answer, your next problem. Please see the following example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = '''
<tr class="ghj">
    <td><span class="city-sh"><sh src="./citys/1.jpg" alt="boy" title="boy" /></span><a href="./membercity.php?mode=view&amp;u=12563">port_new_cape</a></td>
    <td class="position"><a href="./search.php?id=12563&amp;sr=positions" title="Search positions">452</a></td>
    <td class="details"><div>South</div></td>
    <td>May 09, 1997</td>
    <td>Jan 23, 2009 12:05 pm&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="ghj">
    <td><span class="city-sh"><sh src="./citys/1.jpg" alt="boy" title="boy" /></span><a href="./membercity.php?mode=view&amp;u=12563">port_new_cape</a></td>
    <td class="position"><a href="./search.php?id=12563&amp;sr=positions" title="Search positions">452</a></td>
    <td class="details"><div>South</div></td>
    <td>May 09, 1997</td>
    <td>Jan 24, 2009 12:05 pm&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="ghj">
    <td><span class="city-sh"><sh src="./citys/1.jpg" alt="boy" title="boy" /></span><a href="./membercity.php?mode=view&amp;u=12563">port_new_cape</a></td>
    <td class="position"><a href="./search.php?id=12563&amp;sr=positions" title="Search positions">452</a></td>
    <td class="details"><div>South</div></td>
    <td>May 09, 1997</td>
    <td>Jan 25, 2009 12:05 pm&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
cities = soup.find_all('td', {'class' : 'details'}) 
counter = 0
while len(cities) > counter:
    datesColumn = cities[counter].find_next_siblings('td')
            # Assuming you are interested in second column of date
    if len(datesColumn) == 2:
        print datesColumn[1].string

    counter += 1
```

Output is:

```
Jan 23, 2009 12:05 pm 
Jan 24, 2009 12:05 pm 
Jan 25, 2009 12:05 pm
```

Comment: thanks again, Chandan. could you please give an example of Python debugger too? i saw this term and tried a few times however not successful...

Comment: Use Eclipse as an IDE. Install PyDev plugin in Eclipse. More details are here: http://pydev.org/

Comment: Btw, if you are not planning to use Eclipse or Pydev then in most basic form you can use Pdb. Go through this doc: http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html. And, dont forget to up-vote the answer if it solved your problem :P

Comment: thanks Chandan... i tried your solution and it works, but there are 2 problems: 1. it only picks the wanted in the 1st paragraph of the webpage source codes (my example is just a part), there are many similar paragraphs. 2.it picks both time texts however i only want "Jan 23, 2009 12:05 pm". would you mind help again? thanks.

Comment: thanks Chandan. I am digesting it. For the row “print datesColumn[1].string” it gives error message “RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded”. When removed the “.string”, it works but the results are furnished with <td> and </td>. When change it to “print datesColumn[1].renderContents()”. It works too. So is it the problem of my Python version?

Comment: Hi Mark, I dont see any obvious reason for causing recusion unless it is being done by BeautifulSoup. It is also does not appear to be an issue with your Python installation. Will it be possible for you to share your HTML file (unless it contains some confidential content).

Comment: Hello Chandan, you are great. regretfully i can't share the raw company file.